# removing www and index.php from url in symfony

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, symfony1, no-www

I've been searching for like 3 or 4 hours without any result(before searching I played with rules for an hour but couldn't do it)

I don't know if you've noticed or no but google uses www like this

when it has no subdomain it will be www.google.com/blabla and
when there is a subdomain it will be earth.google.com/blabla

This is the first part

And the second part, as you know in symfony urls are like domain.com/index.php/test and thanks to the symfony .htaccess file you can access it via domain.com/test
So here is what I tried so hard to achieve

domain.com/test redirect to www.domain.com/test

www.sub.domain.com/blabla redirect to sub.domain.com/blabla

www.sub.domain.com/ redirect to sub.domain.com (without any index.php XD)

One of the annoying problems I had was redirecting from domain.com/ to www.domain.com was that after redirect it was like www.domain.com/index.php (And I hate index.php :P)

So is there any way with one redirect solve this problem?
I'm sure I'm not the only one who needs something like this and might be an idea for other people who are going to have their site with symfony or other frameworks
Thanks

Here is my complete htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # The admin subdomain returns to the backend
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.mydomain\..*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ backend.php [QSA,L]

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301]

  # we skip all files with .something
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have     
no_script_name:         true
in the prod sections of your settings.yml, and:
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
in htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

In your VHOST config:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also note that from a esthetical point of view you might prefer to remove the www., looking from the technical angle (DNS, cookies, ...), it is always better to prefix with www., and redirect in the opposite way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't meet what I have asked for
I'm going to do as you say(including www for all of the domains but the problem of redirecting from domain.com to www.domain.com persists since it redirects to www.domain.com/index.php

Comment: It would only redirect to /index.php if the original request contained /index.php. I think you are missing something else.

Comment: No it doesn't need to have index.php
Since when you enter domain.com since the default page is index.php and since you have $1 at the end of www.domain.com it will become www.domain.com/index.php

Comment: Maybe you have your rewrite rules in the wrong order. This one should be pretty much at the top. Post your entire .htaccess if you'd like more support.

Comment: I can't post my entire htaccess since it seems comments have character limits

Comment: You can always update your original question with the extra info.